# Sending a message to specific client as a client using SignalR in Java

Tags: java, signalr

I can broadcast messages through hub, I can get the connection id, but the issue is sending a message to specific client/connection.

I just need information on how to send a message to specific client as a client from Java, for instance I am connected C# back end and I have connected to the hub,  now I want to instruct the hub in Java that the message I am sending you is to send to a specific client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients) on the server you can use either:

- `Clients.Client(connectionId)` if you have connection id
- `Clients.User(userId)` if you have user id

If you need to send a message from the client to a different client you need to invoke a server method and pass the target connection id/user id and invoke the method on a target client from the server using the provided id.

Comment: It's basically C# based that provides such interfaces to achieve such purpose, I was specifically asking for any help on how to achieve same thing through java using  'signalr-client-sdk.jar' .

Comment: The APIs I provided are on the server side. You use them in the Hub methods on the server. You invoke these hub methods from the client like any other hub method. SignalR does not have a peer-to-peer model so all the calls need to be routed via server.